# connect to Zookeeper via kazoo lib with credentials

Tags: python, apache-zookeeper, kazoo

I am trying to protect my zookeeper with credentials.

Until now i've used the following code in order to connect to zookeeper:

```
zk = KazooClient(hosts=HOSTS)
zk.start()
```

Now, in order to add credentials i've added an auth with `addauth digest username:password` command and set ACL to the znode with `setAcl /znode auth:username:password:crdwa`.

now when I try to connect to the zookeeper server via zkCli I get

> kazoo.exceptions.NoAuthError

as excepted.

But how I can pass the auth credentials to the `KazooClient`?

I can create ACL credentials with

```
ACL = make_digest_acl("username", "password", all=True) 
CRED = make_digest_acl_credential("username", "password")
```

and add `default_acl`, `auth_data` like

```
zk = KazooClient(hosts=HOSTS, default_acl=ACL, auth_data=[CRED])
```

but i still cannot connect via python.

How I should authenticate the zookeeper server via kazoo client?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `auth_data` should be pass as digest, for example:

`KazooClient(hosts=HOSTS, auth_data=[("digest", "user:pass")])`